# Power BI - Trying to create an Export to PDF button using Power Automate

Tags: powerbi, pdf-generation, powerbi-desktop, power-automate, powerbi-embedded

I have a 4-tab report in Power BI. In Power BI Desktop, I can click on File -> Export-> Export to PDF, and it will run through each tab and create a single PDF, then pull it up in my PDF Reader (e.g. Adobe Acrobat).

I basically want to duplicate this same functionality in Power BI Embedded, but by having a PDF icon button at the top of each tab (note that if the user clicks the PDF icon on any tab, I still want it to create a PDF containing all four tabs).

I tried this using Power Automate, but it appears to only allow me to create a PDF based on specific data items, then save the file to a Sharepoint or OneDrive drive.

How can I do this using Power Automate?

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to use Power Automate? If the exportToFile API meets your needs, give it a shot: https://learn.microsoft.com/power-bi/developer/embedded/export-to

Comment: Yes, this looks like a valid alternative for what I'm looking to do.